# Is a generalisation between Activities allowed in an UML activity diagram?

Tags: android-activity, uml, diagram

I got two Activities called A("show login site") and B("show login site with error message"). And in the view from the software is A the generalised Activity from B.

Does UML allow a generalisation between them or should i ignore this?

Answer (score 0):

Generalization relationships appear in class, component, and use case diagrams.
There is no "generalization" relationship between  Actions or Activities in Activity Diagram.

Activity diagram are used to explore flow of business process or details of an algorithm generally.

So after your investigation you may wish to implement this in an object oriented way. In that case if you a decide to create hirearchy of Activities [ suppose  A <|------ B (B inherits from A) ], then -if it helps you- you can show it on Class Diagram.

PS: A: show login site B: Show login site with error message   MAY NOT truely show a generalization relationship in software perspective. (depends on your context).